# Got error on if condition "Property isSuccess does not exist on type 'Object'"

Tags: angular, object, angular10

Got error on if condition "Property isSuccess does not exist on type 'Object'"

```
  login(e: userModel) {
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "User/Login", e).subscribe(
  {
    next: data => {
      if (data && data.isSuccess) {
        this.bm.setCookies(data);
        this.route.navigate(['/', 'dashboard']);
      } else {
        alert(data);
      }
    },
    error: error => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
 if (data && data['isSuccess']) {
////
 }
```